# Where can the Java main function be found

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Whether `public static void main(String[] args)` is an inbuilt or user defined or overridden function of some class provided by Java? If it is declared or defined inside some interface or class, where can its declaration be found?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[JLS 12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

> The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings.

Every Java application should have a `main()` method , the JVM will look for the `main()` method while launching the application. This is where the execution starts. No it is not in-built, you define the `main()` method in your class which becomes the starting execution point for your application. The main() method must be `public`, `static`, return `void`, and accept one parameter: a `String` array. Any class with such a `main()` method can be used as the starting point for a Java application.

[JVM spec 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2):

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial class, which is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1). **The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the public class method void main(String[]). The invocation of this method drives all further execution.** Execution of the Java Virtual Machine instructions constituting the main method may cause linking (and consequently creation) of additional classes and interfaces, as well as invocation of additional methods.

Comment: @The New Idiot,"The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the public class method void main(String[])."- does initialization mean here that The Java Virtual Machine allocates memory to static variables of the class,runs the static block or something else?What does 'Initialization of the class before the invocation of the method public static void main (String[])' mean here? Please be specific.

Comment: @ChandanKumar Please be more active in reading the JLS and also [google search](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html).

Answer (score 6):

It's not defined by any interface, the language specification dictates that it is the function the JRE looks for when it begins running.

Answer (score 0):

It is independent of everything you have specified in your answer. When you invoke your interpreter   by calling `java MyClass` your JVM will try to find a method with signature  `public static void main(String[] args)` in your compiled MyClass code(`The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter whose declared type is array of String`). Interpretation will stat from there. It is not  user defined but a kind of specification laid down by `Java Language Specification`.

For more ref - [Check Here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[]args){}

For every java application main function must be declared.Because when we run an application,JVM will look for main function.And main function is not inbuilt.We also call main main function as starting point of application

Public : It is an access specifier.which defines who can access this method.

Static : It can be accessed without creating an instance of Class.

Void : Return type.

main: Name of the method. This method name is searched by JVM as starting point for an application.

String args[] :  parameter to main method.